# Как рассчитать значение, на которое будет увеличиваться основное значение?

Tags: javascript, анимация, setinterval

Даны: 
Начальное значение - `0`;
 Значение, к которому нужно привести Начальное значение: `tween.attrs.radius`;
 Время за которое нужно привести начальное значение к значению `tween.attrs.radius` - `end`;
 И периодичность тактов: `age`
Например:

```
   tween = {
      age: 10,
      end: 200,
      attrs: {
        radius: 50
      }
```

Вопрос: Как рассчитать число, на которое нужно увеличивать начальное значение с каждым тактом, чтобы, когда прошло время указанное в `end` начальное значение равнялось 50?

Я делаю это так:

```
obj.attrs.radius += (0 - tween.attrs.radius) * tween.age / tween.end;
```

Но начальное значение при выполнении этого меньше 50 примерно в 2 раза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var step   = tween.attr.radius/tween.age; // шаг (искомое значение)
var period = tween.end/tween.age;         // с какой периодичностью будем
                                          // прибавлять step
```